Expressing a double-sum of the form $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{h}a_{i+j}$ in terms of single-sums
I'm having trouble understanding and "reindexing" this particular sums, so that there will only be one variable (only $i$ or only $j$) in the end, but there's no need for everything to be under one summation symbol:
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \geq h \geq 1 $.
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{h}a_{ i+j} \tag{$\star$}$$
Since I believe that with triangular sums, we can obtain:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ i+j} = \sum_{k=2}^{n}(k-1)a_{k} + \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}(2n-k+1)a_{k}$$
However if we add and subtract $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=h+1}^{n}a_{ i+j}$ to $(\star)$ in order to make the triangular sums appears, I don't know how to proceed since I cannot calculate this new unknown sum.
Furthermore, what kind of figure/shape are we even summing on for $(\star)$ ?

Have a look at this picture of the index pairs $(i, j)$ for $(n, h) = (7, 4)$. The diagonal lines connect index pairs for fixed sum $i + j = m$. You can modify these parameters in this interactive graphic.

As you can see, the number $N(m)$ of index pairs of sum $m$ is
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccccccc}
  m  & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
\hline 
N(m) & 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 &  2 &  1
\end{array}
$$
This frequency function $N$ steps up from $1$ to $h+1$, stays constant at $h+1$, then steps down from $h+1$ to $1$. This "plateau" function looks like this:

You can work out piecewise formulas for this function explicitly:
$$
N(m) = \begin{cases}
m - 1 & \text{if }\, \phantom{h + {}}2 \leq m \leq h \\
h & \text{if }\, h + 1 \leq m \leq n + 1 \\
n + h - 1 & \text{if }\, n + 2 \leq m \leq n + h
\end{cases}
$$

Now, your double sum is can be indexed by just by $m$ with this frequency function scaling each term:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^h a_{i + j} = \sum_{m=2}^{n+h} N(m)\,a_m. 
$$
